# Github action does not find .NET 8 framework for test, but build works

Tags: c#, visual-studio, github, github-actions

The below workflow fails for the `dotnet test` step. The build before works, so I am sure the framework is restored.

```
.NET location: /usr/share/dotnet/
 No frameworks were found.
```

For testing I have checked the directory, it is there. Also I have tried to set the env var `DOTNET_ROOT: /usr/share/dotnet/` explicitly. Another approach to to set the dependencies a 2nd time directly before the test, no success (this was something I have found as potential solution).

```yaml
 - name: Install dependencies 
   run: dotnet restore
```

Crosschecked the 2 projects (test/application), the version related parts are identical.

```
<TargetFramework>net8.0-windows10.0.17763.0</TargetFramework>
<EnableWindowsTargeting>true</EnableWindowsTargeting>
<SupportedOSPlatformVersion>10.0.17763.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
```

What could the issue be?

```yaml
name: Build and Test workflow
on: [push, workflow_dispatch]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        dotnet-version: [ '8.x' ]

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Setup dotnet ${{ matrix.dotnet-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
        with:
          dotnet-version: ${{ matrix.dotnet-version }}

      # You can test your matrix by printing the current dotnet version
      - name: Display dotnet version
        run: dotnet --version
        
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: dotnet restore

      - name: Build
        run: dotnet build

      - name: Show runtime just to check it is there
        run: |
          ls /usr/share/dotnet/

      - name: Test with dotnet, simplified
        # env:
        #   DOTNET_ROOT: /usr/share/dotnet/
        run: dotnet test

      - name: Test with dotnet, the real thing I wish to run
        run: dotnet test --logger trx --results-directory "TestResults-${{ matrix.dotnet-version }}"
      
      - name: Upload dotnet test results
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: dotnet-results-${{ matrix.dotnet-version }}
          path: TestResults-${{ matrix.dotnet-version }}
          condition: always() # this step will always run, even if the pipeline is cancel
```

Log (partially) install works

```
2024-01-16T20:33:04.1767664Z dotnet-install: Attempting to download using aka.ms link https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Sdk/8.0.101/dotnet-sdk-8.0.101-linux-x64.tar.gz
2024-01-16T20:33:05.4866704Z dotnet-install: Extracting zip from https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Sdk/8.0.101/dotnet-sdk-8.0.101-linux-x64.tar.gz
2024-01-16T20:33:13.5590230Z dotnet-install: Installed version is 8.0.101
2024-01-16T20:33:13.5694506Z dotnet-install: Adding to current process PATH: `/usr/share/dotnet`. Note: This change will be visible only when sourcing script.
2024-01-16T20:33:13.5696730Z dotnet-install: Note that the script does not resolve dependencies during installation.
2024-01-16T20:33:13.5699287Z dotnet-install: To check the list of dependencies, go to https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/install, select your operating system and check the "Dependencies" section.
2024-01-16T20:33:13.5767522Z dotnet-install: Installation finished successfully.
2024-01-16T20:33:13.5933149Z ##[group]Run dotnet --version
2024-01-16T20:33:13.7800075Z 8.0.101
....
2024-01-16T20:33:41.3587598Z A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.
2024-01-16T20:33:41.5843829Z Testhost process for source(s) '/home/runner/work/Sams/Sams/SamsUnitTests/bin/Debug/net8.0-windows10.0.17763.0/SamsUnitTests.dll' exited with error: You must install or update .NET to run this application.
2024-01-16T20:33:41.5854437Z App: /home/runner/work/Sams/Sams/SamsUnitTests/bin/Debug/net8.0-windows10.0.17763.0/testhost.dll
2024-01-16T20:33:41.5856081Z Architecture: x64
2024-01-16T20:33:41.5857865Z Framework: 'Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App', version '8.0.0' (x64)
2024-01-16T20:33:41.5858965Z .NET location: /usr/share/dotnet/
2024-01-16T20:33:41.5859546Z No frameworks were found.
2024-01-16T20:33:41.5860117Z Learn more:
2024-01-16T20:33:41.5860840Z https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed
2024-01-16T20:33:41.5861495Z To install missing framework, download:
2024-01-16T20:33:41.5863115Z https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App&framework_version=8.0.0&arch=x64&rid=linux-x64&os=ubuntu.22.04
2024-01-16T20:33:41.5864673Z . Please check the diagnostic logs for more information.
2024-01-16T20:33:41.6787535Z Test Run Aborted.
```

Comment: The test project is separate from the main one, correct? Could you compare the two .csproj settings?

Comment: Yes, I did this. I have used the same version and requirements in there. First I was getting some errors, which were resolved by that. I will crosscheck another time, but framework etc. should be identical.

Comment: Do a clean build to remove all intermediate obj files on main and child projects.

Comment: Just to understand, isn't any action on github building completely from the scratch? How would my local files interfere with my github build? Or do I misunderstand you?

Comment: The project targets Windows and requires Windows SDK 10.0 and above to compile. So you cannot use Ubuntu as the environment. The manifest you chose was incorrect from the beginning. Please switch to a Windows environment and try again.

Comment: I see, you mean I can build, but not run on ubuntu. makes sense!

Comment: @Lex Li Thanks, this has solved the issue. I got mixed up, as I can do a cross platform build, but of course no cross platform run. The error message was not very clear, so I was completely heading in the wrong direction. Feel free to post your comment as answer, which I will then accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lex Li (in the comments) has pointed me in the right direction:

> The project targets Windows and requires Windows SDK 10.0 and above to
> compile. So you cannot use Ubuntu as the environment. The manifest you
> chose was incorrect from the beginning. Please switch to a Windows
> environment and try again.

Using Windows works. I have used `<EnableWindowsTargeting>true</EnableWindowsTargeting>` and therefor **it is possible to compile** on `ubuntu`.

Furthermore the UNIT tests are not really Windows dependent and would run on `ubuntu`. But I got a `github` warning that build and test use different requirements: The issue was resolved by unifying the two project files in `VS2022` and `github`.

Obviously now the UNIT test is limited running on Windows only. The error message itself is not very clear and I was completely heading in the wrong direction.

```
.NET location: /usr/share/dotnet/
 No frameworks were found.
```

Means cannot run on `ubuntu`.